# AFHTTPRequestOperation intercept start of the operation

Tags: afnetworking

There is setCompletionBlock in AFHTTPRequestOperation.
Is there a way to intercept when AFHTTPRequestOperation starts as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes or no, depending on your meaning of "intercept"…

Since you control when it starts (either by adding it to an NSOperationQueue, or by calling `[operation start]`), no interface is provided for *conditionally* starting.

If you just want to be *notified* when it starts, you can register for the `AFNetworkingOperationDidStartNotification`, which is broadcast when a notification starts.

You can implement it like this:

```
// In some method…
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(HTTPOperationDidStart:) name:AFNetworkingOperationDidStartNotification object:nil];


- (void)HTTPOperationDidStart:(NSNotification *)notification {
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)[notification object];

    if (![operation isKindOfClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]]) {
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@ '%@': %@", [operation.request HTTPMethod], [[operation.request URL] absoluteString], [operation.request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
            break;
}
```

This sample code is a slightly modified excerpt from [AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger), which logs AFNetworking information to your console.